# Tratar objetos do array vindos do AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Boa tarde pessoal, li o fórum todo e tentei várias coisas, mas não consigo extrair os dados do array para manipular.

Bem, estou montando um sistema no qual, após efetuar uma venda, ele salva a venda em uma tabela com o nome do vendedor e o total da venda.

Eu consegui extrair esses dados e salvar.

A outra parte é pegar os produtos da venda e salvar em outra tabela e associar o id da venda acima nos produtos.

Meu Array vem assim:

```
 array(3) {
  ["vendafinal"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["vendaproduto"]=>
      string(10) "Produto 02"
      ["vendaqtd"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ["vendavalor"]=>
      string(1) "5"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["vendaproduto"]=>
      string(10) "Produto 01"
      ["vendaqtd"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["vendavalor"]=>
      string(2) "10"
    }
  }
  ["vendedor"]=>
  string(4) "Erik"
  ["totalvenda"]=>
  string(3) "100"
}
```

O Vendedor e o total da venda consegui puxar com:

```
$vendedor = $_POST['vendedor'];
$totalvenda = $_POST['totalvenda'];
$data = date("Y-m-d");
$hora = date("H:i:s");
```

Salvo no Banco e ele exibe perfeitamente. A outra parte é salvar os produtos em outra tabela, com a quantidade e o valor do produto e também o id da venda anterior. Mas ta osso, não consegui trabalhar esses objetos nem a pau. Tentei foreach, for e nada.

Eu envio os dados para essa página PHP via AJAX:

```
function insereVenda() {
        var vendafinal = [];
        var linhas = $("tbody>tr");
        var vendedor = $("#vendedor").val();
        var totalvenda = $("#totalvendas").text();

        linhas.each(function () {
            var produto = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
            var quantidade = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
            var valor = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").text();


            var sale = {
                vendaproduto: produto,
                vendaqtd: quantidade,
                vendavalor: valor

            };

             vendafinal.push(sale);


        });


        var dados = {
            vendafinal: vendafinal,
            vendedor: vendedor,
            totalvenda: totalvenda
        };

        $.post("salvarvendabkp.php", dados, function (retorna) {
            $("#retorna1").html(retorna);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Erik,

Como você está usando um array multidimensional, é necessário usar um foreach (por exemplo) para acessar os produtos e salvá-los no banco de dados.

Segue o exemplo:

```php
$vendafinal = $_POST['vendafinal'];
$venda_id = 123; // esse seria o id do registro que você acabou de salvar na primeira tabela

foreach($vendafinal as $produto) {
    salvarProduto($produto['vendaproduto'], $produto['vendaqtd'], $produto['vendavalor'], $venda_id);
}

function salvarProduto($nome, $quantidade, $valor, $venda_id)
{
    // aqui você faz as validações necessárias e salva no banco de dados
}
```

No exemplo do Array que você colocou, a quantidade e o valor estão com formato de `string`. Verifique se isso não sendo verificado em alguma validação dos dados.